# Q: Simplifying Flutter switch statement

Tags: flutter, dart, logic

How to simplify the switch statement in flutter?
I found that they have solution in java string, which using console.log, but i can't find the solution in flutter/dart.

For example i have below code, is it possible to be simplified?
Basically, it has 3 variable that has 2 condition 'true/false'

```
bool checkUposatha = true;
bool newMoonOnly = true;
bool fullMoonOnly = false;

 switch (checkUposatha) {
    //Uposatha | newMoonOnly | fullMoonOnly
    case true:
      switch (newMoonOnly) {
        case true:
          switch (fullMoonOnly) {
            case true: //true|true|true
              if (mp == 3 || mp == 1) {
                print(printresult);
                break;
              }
              break;
            case false: //true|true|false
              if (mp == 3) {
                print(printresult);
              }
              break;
            default: //true|any|any
              print(printresult);
          }
          break;
        case false:
          switch (fullMoonOnly) {
            case true: //true/false/true
              if (mp == 1) {
                print(printresult);
              }
              break;
            case false: //true/false/false ==> same as default
              if (mp == 3 || mp == 1) {
                print(printresult);
              }
              break;
            default: //true/any/any
              if (mp == 3 || mp == 1) {
                print(printresult);
              }
              break;
          }

          break;
        default: //true/any/any
          if (mp == 3 || mp == 1) {
            print(printresult);
          }
          break;
      }
      break;
    case false: //false/false/false
      print(printresult);
      break;
    default: //any/any/any
      print(printresult);
      break;
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes, it is better avoiding to use `switch` at all, especially in your example, where each branch starts with an `if`. I would just use a chain of `if` - `else if` and maybe `else`, to make things look clearer. In other words, what you are doing is splitting your logic between a `switch` and several inner `if`. This is harder to read than just using `if`'s.

Comment: I would add this. Usually, for simple things, when the logic is as complex as in your example, I start brainstorming to find if I didn't miss something and complexified things unnecessarily. Usually, thinking twice about the conditions (maybe merging some), or inverting nested conditions, could reduce complexity. Anyway, in your case, I would think again about the problem from scratch because my intuition tells me that you overcomplexified things and lost control of your logic, even if your code provides you the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your thought, do you have any suggestion, how would you build it, if there are 3 variables : a , b , c and each variable could be true/false condition and the return value is depend on combination of those 3 variables of true/false condition.

Comment: If you're really lost in your conditions, you could write down a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and then figure out what the most simple logical expression you could write for this table.

Answer (score 0):

So, in this case you have to use if else and language does not matter here. Because you want to check both ways for example, if **newMoonOnly** is true, you want to check the status of **fullMoonOnly**, else if **newMoonOnly** is false, you are again trying to check status of **fullMoonOnly**. So in this situation I would suggest to use *if else* in any language. Because either in c, c++, or in python or in swift you would have to use if else.